# How to write a map of x and y coordinates of points?

Tags: jquery, dictionary, coordinates

I trying to find a tool or jquery plugin that can show a map of x and y coordinates, do someone knows anything about something that can fix it?

I like to get it like a Google Map with panning and zooming but this is only x and y coordinates of points on the map from a game map.

I am open for any suggestions but jQuery, html and css is what i hope for....

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own maps for Google Maps ([UESP is an excellent example](http://www.uesp.net/maps/obmap/obmap.shtml)), that way you will get a powerful and well tested API to work with. UESP also has an [article describing how their map works](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/UESPWiki%3aOblivion_Map_Design). It is a bit dated since they use Google Maps V2 but the main concept is the same so you shouldn't run into any serious problems porting this to V3 (or you could just stay with V2).